# In the last statement, can i prove the contrapositive of it to be true to prove the statement?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have worked out the problem **A B C**, my question is in the last statement " If the numbers e, π, π^2, e^2 and eπ are irrational, prove that at most one of the numbers π+e, π−e, π^2−e^2, π^2+e^2 is rational." can i prove the contrapositive of it (i.e.at least two of the numbers π+e, π−e, π^2−e^2, π^2+e^2 is rational, then at least one of the e, π, π^2, e^2 and eπ are rational) to be true to prove the statement?

What does it mean to say that a number x is irrational?
Prove by contradiction statements A and B below, where p and q are real numbers.

**A**: If pq is irrational, then at least one of p and q is irrational.

**B**: If p + q is irrational, then at least one of p and q is irrational.

Disprove by means of a counterexample statement C below, where p and q are real numbers.

**C**: If p and q are irrational, then p + q is irrational.

If the numbers e, π, π^2, e^2 and eπ are irrational, prove that at most one of the numbers π+e,
π−e, π^2−e^2, π^2+e^2 is rational.

Comment: What have you tried?  Surely, for part A, you can show that $p,q\in \mathbb Q\implies pq\in \mathbb Q$, no?

Comment: That comment looks like it should be part of the question. The title looks like it should be in the question too. And what's all the other stuff in the question? Are we supposed to say something about A, B, and C, or just the last paragraph?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, proving the contrapositive also proves the statement.

We need to be sure the contrapositive is really a contrapositive.
"At least two" is the exact negation of "at most one,"
and "at least one is rational" is the exact negation of "all are irrational,"
so I think you're doing OK so far.